# Check if NSArray contains some int

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray, nspredicate, nsnumber

I have a `NSMutableArray` of `NSNumbers`. Basically I just want to check if any of the `NSNumbers` in the array = some value.

I could iterate through the array, checking one by one, by this is by no means optimal.

I also tried and failed using `containsObject`, because this only works if the id's are the same.

I read something about `NSPredicate`, this seems like a good solution, but I am not sure on how to use it with an `NSArray`.

Any answer is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: If your array is unsorted there is no more effecient way than O(n) to check what you want and the iterating does that. Any other way will first have to sort the array (O(nlogn)) before it can search it more efficiently (O(logn))

Comment: The array isn't sorted using any sorting methods, but the manner I'm adding objects to it, the array is already in numerical order. How does it being sorted help?

Comment: If it is sorted you can binary search it with O(logn) speed

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Iterating through the array is the best approach here. This is exactly what the `containsObject` method is doing under the covers. You could sort the array, but that wouldn't give you very much in terms of efficiency.

If you want to be able to look up values quicker than O(n), `NSArray/NSMutableArray` is probably not the right data structure for you.

Comment: Thanks, what would be a better structure for doing this sort of thing?

Comment: Hard to say without knowing exactly what you're trying to do. Maybe you should describe your scenario in another SO question?

Comment: NSArray/NSMutableArray IS the right data structure for fast lookup! Just use CFArrayBSearchValues(…)

Answer (score 20):

Inspired by bernstein I looked up some more info about the and i found `CFArrayContainsValue`

```
BOOL CFArrayContainsValue(CFArrayRef theArray, CFRange range, const void *value);
```

Example:

```
NSArray *numbers;
NSNumber *value;
BOOL found = CFArrayContainsValue ( (__bridge CFArrayRef)numbers, 
                                    CFRangeMake(0, numbers.count), 
                                    (CFNumberRef)value );
```

Works like a charm and is really fast!

Comment: What is `selectedItems`?

Comment: Good catch, probably forgot to change it. Updated the answer for you!

Answer (score 12):

```
    NSPredicate *valuePredicate=[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"self.intValue == %d",[myValueNumber intValue]];

    if ([[numbersArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:valuePredicate] count]!=0) {   
        // FOUND
    }

    else  {
       //NOT FOUND
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

a little late, but since the array is already ordered (sorted) you should use CFArrayBSearchValues() which does binary search.

example with numbers:

```
NSArray *array; // or NSMutableArray
NSNumber *value; // search value
CFArrayBSearchValues((__bridge CFArrayRef)array, CFRangeMake(0, array.count),                   
        (CFNumberRef)value, (CFComparatorFunction)CFNumberCompare, NULL);
```

Answer (score 2):

Iterating through NSArray is OK if you don't do it too much. And that's what "containObject" does. 
But I found that when you need lots and lots of those checks, especially if the arrays are big, it will slow your app...

So if it's a check you need to do often, you can always dictionary instead of array. Where the key will be the NSNumber, and the field will be the number of times it appears in the array. 
Then, you use "ObjectForKey" to check if the number is in the array, you use "allKeys" to get all the values if needed, etc...

Good luck

Answer (score 1):

You can simply check like this:

```
if ([myArray indexOfObject:@(myNumber)] == NSNotFound) {
    NSLog(@"myArray' contauns 'myNumber");
}
```

Keep Coding.......... :)